# For loop with list not working as expected Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script which checks a log file for lines of text and if the line exists restarts a service and resets/archives the log. I got it working before with 1 "checkstring" if you will, but I've been struggling to get it to work with a list of strings. Could anyone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$serviceName = "MySQL80"
$file = "test.txt"
$pwd = "C:\tmp\"

$checkStrings = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# Add amount of checkstrings
$checkStrings.add("Unhandled error. Error message: Error retrieving response.")
$checkStrings.add("Unhandled error. Error message: Error retrieving response. Second")

$logName = "ServiceCheck.log"
$backupFolder = "Archive"

$logString = (Get-Date).ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss"), " - The service has been reset and the log moved to backup" -Join ""
Set-Location -Path $pwd
if(Test-Path -Path $file) {
    if(Test-Path -Path $backupFolder) {
    
    } else {
        New-Item -Path $pwd -Name $backupFolder -ItemType "director"
    }

    foreach ($element in $checkStrings) {
        $containsWord = $fileContent | %{$_ -match $element}
        if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
            Restart-Service -Name $serviceName

            $backupPath = $pwd, "\", $backupFolder, "\", $date, ".log" -join ""
            $currentFile = $pwd, "\", $file -join ""
            Copy-Item $currentFile -Destination $backupPath
            Get-Content $currentFile | select-string -pattern $checkString -notmatch | Out-File $currentFile
            if(Test-Path -Path $logName) {
                Add-Content $logName $logString
            } else {
                $logString | Out-File -FilePath $logName
            }
    
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: It is impossible for us to tell the failure because we would need a copy of the folder/files you are trying to read.  I would use Write-Host variable to isolate where the script is not retrieving the correct files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It made me realise I completely missed the line of code reading the file into the $fileContent variable. Thank you!